# Como concatenar celdas de texto con vba

Tags: vba

Estoy intentando concatenar varios campos para formar una direccion completa

```
dirFacturacionRange.Value = hojaClientes.Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 3) + vbCrLf + 
hojaClientes.Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 5)
```

Pero me da este error

[image: error]

Pero ambas columnas son de tipo general e incluso si pongo la columna CP a formato texto tampoco me deja

[image: columnas]

Alguna idea?

Salu2

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es sustituir el simbolo mas or el &

```
dirFacturacionRange.Value = hojaClientes.Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 3) & vbCrLf &
```

hojaClientes.Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 5)

Salu2